# C#:The type or namespace name '?Attribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, attributes, mshtml

I was coding my program and out of nowhere I get the following:

> The type or namespace name '?Attribute' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I got it after trying to add the dll: mshtml

I removed it but the error doesnt go away.

Another error I get is:

> Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

and...

> 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window,
>   string)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type

I tried closing out of the IDE and reopening it to see if the error went away but it didnt.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT: Here is a sample code where the error comes from. Note several other items in my code have the same of similar errors:

The error is in

> if (webBrowser1

and

> Show

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Text here"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("TText.......");
                }
```

Comment: can you post the code that these errors are coming from?

Comment: It looks like you have an missing closing tag somewhere which is causing knock on errors. Do you have any code you could post?

Comment: @jameslewis Check my post I updated it

Comment: In the first piece of code you posted is this the whole line? As you would need a closing bracket and also need code which returns a boolean value. It would be beneficial if you could post the whole of the line which the first error is being reported from.

Comment: it seems to me like theres an error else where in the code file-probably in your using statements? cant tell without all the code tho...

Comment: The error about the attribute appears here string[] strArray in my code @jameslewis

Comment: @jameslewis Here is my using statements: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using mshtml;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to `?Attribute` name suggests you have malformed attribute declaration, most likely followed by non-ASCII unicode character - check your code file for misplaced occurrences of "[" (open square bracket) before any other errors.

Comment: I checked and there were no misplaced open brackets :/ @MagnatLU

Comment: You said your first error appears at `string[] strArray`. Check if there is no character between brackets in array declaration. It's a long shot, but I still think `?` in `?Attribute` stands for rogue unicode character, since `[?]` would give different error message and `[(non-breaking-space-here)]` gives exactly the same error.

Comment: I fixed the errors by removing all the code I put prior to putting the dll mshtml